# Apache Flink - multiple output lines

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect, bigdata

I am trying to run flink job as below to read data from Apache Kafka & print:

**Java Program**

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "test.net:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink_consumer");
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "dev.com:2181,dev2.com:2181,dev.com:2181/dev2");
    properties.setProperty("topic", "topic_name");

    DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>("topic_name", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

            messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

                public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                    return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
                }
            }).print();

            env.execute();
```

**Scala Code**

```
  var properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "msg01.staging.bigdata.sv2.247-inc.net:9092");
  properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink_consumer");
  properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "host33.dev.swamp.sv2.tellme.com:2181,host37.dev.swamp.sv2.tellme.com:2181,host38.dev.swamp.sv2.tellme.com:2181/staging_sv2");
  properties.setProperty("topic", "sv2.staging.rtdp.idm.events.omnichannel");
  var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
  var stream:DataStream[(String)] = env
.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082[String]("sv2.staging.rtdp.idm.events.omnichannel", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
  stream.print();
  env.execute();
```

Whenever I run this in app in eclipse, I see below out to start with:

03/27/2017 20:06:19 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.

*03/27/2017 20:06:19    Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to SCHEDULED 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to DEPLOYING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to SCHEDULED 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to DEPLOYING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to SCHEDULED 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to DEPLOYING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to SCHEDULED 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to DEPLOYING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to RUNNING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to RUNNING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to RUNNING 
03/27/2017 20:06:19 Source: Custom Source -> Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to RUNNING*

Question I have is:

1) Why am I seeing 4 instance of sink in all the cases(Scheduled, deployed and running).

2) For every line received in Apache Kafka, I see being printed here multiple times mostly 4 times. What's a reason?

Ideally I want to read each lines only once and do further processing with it. Any input/help will be appreciable!

Comment: How many partitions does your topic have?

Comment: Topic I am using have PartitionCount:6 & ReplicationFactor:2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the program in the `LocalStreamEnvironment` (which you get when you call `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()` in an IDE) the default parallelism of all operators is equal to the number of CPU cores.

So in your example each operator is parallelized into four subtasks. In the log you see message for each of these four subtasks (`3/4` indicates this is the third of in total four tasks).

You can control the number of subtasks by calling `StreamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(int)` or call `setParallelism(int)` on each individual operator.

Given your program, the Kafka records should not be replicated. Each record should only be printed once. However, since the records are written in parallel, line of output is prefixed by `x>` where `x` indicates the id of the parallel subtask that emitted the line.

Comment: Thanks for your input! As per your comment, I tried following: 1) StreamExecutionEnvironment.setDefaultLocalParallelism(1); as I just want to print or process every record once. This works better than before I see some lines printed only once but after a while it again start behaving similar and print multiple lines. 2) env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(); env.setParallelism(1); Still it print output line multiple times. Eventually I need to process this output & put data in cassandra, so my main concern is it will process & store multiple lines. Pls share your inputs!

Comment: The programs that you posted to not replicate the data. Are you sure that the data is not replicated inside the Kafka topic?

Comment: Checked, seems like there are some issues with events printed in Kafka as well. Thanks a lot Fabian!